# facebook graph api getUser returns 0

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk

I create new app and try to get user 
require_once 'facebook.php';

```
$this->fb = new Facebook(array(
          'appId'  => APPID,
          'secret' => APPSECRET,
          'cookie' => true
        ));
$user = $this->fb->getUser();
```

I am using new sdk 3.2.2. On my testing environment its work until today. But now its always returns 0.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Just based on that code there is no login handling for example `getLoginUrl()`, unless the user has logged in through a login flow, `$user` will always be zero.